# Python: Modify exception/error output

Tags: python, error-handling

I have a script that does something like the following...

```
import socket

hostIP=sys.argv[1]

if socket.inet_aton(hostIP):
    # Do something with valid ip address
else:
    # Print error message
```

Which works fine for valid addresses, however when I try an invalid address it does not work (i.e. printing my error message), and throws out a socket error...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "addNew.py", line 35, in <module>
    if socket.inet_aton(hostIP):
socket.error: illegal IP address string passed to inet_aton
```

Any thoughts on how I can achieve what I want (i.e. just a simple message rather than the socket error).

Thanks in advance,

MHibbin

UPDATE: Working(ish) script

```
import os
import sys
import fileinput
import platform
import subprocess
import re
import socket

hostsFile = "hosts.txt"
hostsLookFile = "hosts.csv"
hostsURLFileLoc = "urls.conf"
plat = platform.system()
currentDir = "C:/Program Files/Splunk/etc/apps/gtvm/bin"
hostsFileLoc = currentDir + "/" + hostsFile
hostsLookFileLoc = currentDir + "/../lookups/" + hostsLookFile
hostsURLFileLoc = currentDir + "/../default/" + hostsURLFileLoc
hostIP = sys.argv[1]
hostName = sys.argv[2]
hostURL = sys.argv[3]
hostMan = sys.argv[4]
hostModel = sys.argv[5]
hostType = sys.argv[6]
hostDC = sys.argv[7]

#pat = re.compile(^hostIP\s+)

#test = pat.match(hostIP)
#if test:
#   print "Acceptable ip address"
#else:
#   print "Unacceptable ip address"


try:
    socket.inet_aton(hostIP)
except socket.error as e:
    print "Unacceptable ip address", e
else:
    print "Acceptable ip address, proceeding..."
    print "Checking host if " + hostIP + " exists..."
    if not hostIP in open(hostsFileLoc).read():
        print hostIP + " does not yet exist, checking valid required input..."
        if hostName != "*" and hostIP != "*":
            print "...processing..."
            with open(hostsFileLoc,'a+') as hostsFilePython, open(hostsLookFileLoc, 'a+') as hostsLookFileCSV, open(hostsURLFileLoc, 'a+') as 

hostsURLPython:
                print "..host IP adddress for ping testing.."
                hostsFilePython.write(hostIP + "\n")
                print "..and, all values for referencing.."
                hostsLookFileCSV.write(hostIP + "," + hostName + "," + hostURL + "," + hostMan + "," + hostModel + "," + hostType + "," + 

hostDC + "," + "\n")
                if hostURL != "*": 
                    "..adding URL for webping testing.."
                    hostsURLPython.write("[" + hostName + "]\n" + "url = " + hostURL + "\n" + "sleep = 60" + "\n" + "\n")
                    print "done!"

        else:
            print "..failed! - Both host IP address and host name required"
    else:
        print hostIP + " already exists, please review lookups."
#except socket.error as e:
#   print "Unacceptable ip address", e
```

Comment: How about catching the exception?

Comment: you are putting a colon after it: `socket.inet_aton(hostIP):`, which shouldn't be there. It is also better to put all the other code from `print "Acceptable ip address, proceeding..."` to `print hostIP + " already exists, please review lookups."` in an else after the except, as shown in my answer.

Comment: Modified my script to match that. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `try`and `except`.

```
import socket

hostIP=sys.argv[1]

try:
    socket.inet_aton(hostIP)
except socket.error as e:
    print "Error:", e
else:
    # Do something with valid ip address
```

First you try to run `socket.inet_aton(hostIP)`, if it fails it prints the error message, if it succeeds, it does some code under the `else`. You put the other code under `else` instead of in the `try`, to avoid catching exceptions that are raised by the other code.

---

UPDATE:

```
import platform
import subprocess
import re
import socket

hostsFile = "hosts.txt"
hostsLookFile = "hosts.csv"
hostsURLFileLoc = "urls.conf"
plat = platform.system()
currentDir = "C:/Program Files/Splunk/etc/apps/gtvm/bin"
hostsFileLoc = currentDir + "/" + hostsFile
hostsLookFileLoc = currentDir + "/../lookups/" + hostsLookFile
hostsURLFileLoc = currentDir + "/../default/" + hostsURLFileLoc
hostIP = sys.argv[1]
hostName = sys.argv[2]
hostURL = sys.argv[3]
hostMan = sys.argv[4]
hostModel = sys.argv[5]
hostType = sys.argv[6]
hostDC = sys.argv[7]

#pat = re.compile("\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}")

#test = pat.match(hostIP)
#if test:
#   print "Acceptable ip address"
#else:
#   print "Unacceptable ip address"


try:
    socket.inet_aton(hostIP)
except socket.error as e:
    print "Unacceptable ip address", e
else:
    print "Acceptable ip address, proceeding..."
    print "Checking host if " + hostIP + " exists..."
    if not hostIP in open(hostsFileLoc).read():
        print hostIP + " does not yet exist, checking valid required input..."
        if hostName != "*" and hostIP != "*":
            print "...processing..."
            with open(hostsFileLoc,'a+') as hostsFilePython, open(hostsLookFileLoc, 'a+') as hostsLookFileCSV, open(hostsURLFileLoc, 'a+') as hostsURLPython:
                print "..host IP adddress for ping testing.."
                hostsFilePython.write(hostIP + "\n")
                print "..and, all values for referencing.."
                hostsLookFileCSV.write(hostIP + "," + hostName + "," + hostURL + "," + hostMan + "," + hostModel + "," + hostType + "," + hostDC + "," + "\n")
                if hostURL != "*": 
                    "..adding URL for webping testing.."
                    hostsURLPython.write("[" + hostName + "]\n" + "url = " + hostURL + "\n" + "sleep = 60" + "\n" + "\n")
                    print "done!"

        else:
            print "..failed! - Both host IP address and host name required"
    else:
        print hostIP + " already exists, please review lookups."
```

Answer (score 2):

To elaborate on my initial comment about using exceptions, create a function that returns `True` or `False` based on the validity of the address:

```
import socket

def check_ip(addr):
    try: 
        socket.inet_aton(addr)
        return True
    except socket.error:
        return False
```

then

```
check_ip('apple')
False

check_ip('74.125.225.98')
True
```

Comment: Bare excepts are not recommended because they catch _all_ exceptions. Catch only what you want to handle.

Comment: @MRAB how would I only catch that exception then?

Comment: Ah yep, sorry I see now :)... Long day :( and i'm a newbie... as you can probably tell

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following template, so that the socket error is trapped.

```
try:
    your block here
except socket.error:
    print "your message"
```

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
not hostIP in open(hostsFileLoc).read()
```

will read the entire file as a single string and then look for `hostIP` in that string. That will also find partial matches, such as `"92.168.1.21"` in `"192.168.1.2"`.

Comment: I was actually going to post a question about that, thanks for noticing.. can I make it so it's an exact match only i.e. in regex something like "^hostIP[\s\.]*"

Comment: I'd probably use a set instead, eg. `hostIP not in set(line.rstrip() for line in open(hostsFileLoc))`. The `.rstrip()` is to remove the `"\n"` line ending.

Answer (score 0):

Some Python code you will use will throw an exception. So, you must write your code to accomodate exceptions like this:

```
import socket

hostIP=sys.argv[1]

try:
  socket.inet_aton(hostIP):
  return True
except socket_error:
  return False
```